# Cómo puedo utilizar correctamente un objeto PDO para una consulta SELECT

Tags: php, pdo

He intentado seguir las instrucciones de PHP para hacer consultas SELECT, pero no estoy seguro de la mejor manera de hacerlo.

index.php

```
/* CONSULTA CATEGORÍA PARA MENU */
    public function cCategory()
    {
        $db = getBD();
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category");
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return true;
    }
```

category.php

```
$object = new myObject();    
$menus = $object->cCategory();

    if(count($menus) > 0)
    {

        foreach ($menus as $menu) {
            $data .= '<tr>
                    <td>' . $number . '</td>
                    <td>' . $menu['cid'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $menu['cname'] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $menu['clink'] . '</td>
                </tr>';
        }
    } else {
        $data .= '<tr><td colspan="6">No hay resultado</td></tr>';
    }

    $data .= '</table>';

    echo $data;
```

Comment: Creo que count($menus) (si es que no está definitivamente mal) no es la manera de validar los registros devueltos. Para eso existe $menus->rowCount()

Comment: Lo de count no es problema, incluso haciendo `if ($menus) { }` creo que funcionaría. El problema mayor lo veo en el `return`de la función `cCategory()`, pues estás devolviendo `true` y no el array que esperas en tu llamada para procesar los datos. Algo así: `$datos= $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  return $datos;` En la situación actual, cuando haces: `$menus = $object->cCategory();` ... `$menus` será igual a `true`o a `false`y nada más.

Comment: @A.Cedano correcto, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si la función que realiza la consulta devuelve siempre true, cómo podría comportarse como array?

Debieras hacer, en cambio:

```
public function cCategory()
{
    $db = getBD();
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM category");
    $sql->execute();
    return $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```